# Error showing up when using knitr but no error when executing the same command in console

Tags: r, dataframe, knitr, gsub

I have a report that needs to be written down on data acquired from weather databases. Till now, every command executed in console has given good results but I'm having some strange issues with knitr when trying to output a simple HTML report with those same commands and I feel its a bug because this should NOT be happening.

It basically involves using the gsub() command for certain values that needed replacements. In usual command execution, I was able to replace every required content that needed replacement through appropriate commands but those very same commands gave this error when knitting to HTML:

```
Quitting from lines 81-92 (experiment.Rmd) 
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "PROPDMGEXP", value = numeric(0)) : 
replacement has 0 rows, data has 902298
Calls: <Anonymous> ... withVisible -> eval -> eval -> $<- -> $<-.data.frame
Execution halted
```

I was using this command:

```
df$column <- gsub('some content', 'replace', df$column)
```

Its really simple but knitr won't let me publish a report. For more reference, a column named PROPDMGEXP had character values that I replaced them with numerals (0-2), like so:

```
PROPDMGEXP
K
K
M
NA
```

I replaced them with 0-2 depending on the data but why is knitr giving me errors on this?

EDIT: This the full reference code just in case:

```
url <- 'some url'
download.file('url', distil = 'xyz.zip')
unzip('xyz.zip')
read.table(xyz.rds)
xyz$PROPDMGEXP <- gsub('K', '1', xyz$PROPDMGEXP)
```

When I paste the same code in a Rmd file and knit it to HTML, the error occurs at the last line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After googling "PROPDMGEXP" I found a publication on [Rpubs](https://rpubs.com/thuphung88/127863). Using this I located the dataset and tried the following using an Rmd file:

```
library(data.table)
wr <- fread("repdata_data_StormData.csv")
unique(wr$PROPDMGEXP)

##  [1] "K" "M" ""  "B" "m" "+" "0" "5" "6" "?" "4" "2" "3" "h" "7" "H" "-"
## [18] "1" "8"
```

Then

```
wr$PROPDMGEXP <- gsub("K", "0", wr$PROPDMGEXP)
unique(wr$PROPDMGEXP)

##  [1] "0" "M" ""  "B" "m" "+" "5" "6" "?" "4" "2" "3" "h" "7" "H" "-" "1" 
## [18] "8"
```

It seems to work fine. Can you maybe provide more information regarding your problem? What exactly did you write?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I did exactly what you did, except I used the usual read.table command instead of fread(). I was also able to replace the same content as you did, replacing K with 1 and so on but only through the usual procedure. However, when I try to knit this same code to an HTML output, knitr throws of this error that I mentioned above.

Comment: Hi, The code I posted above was executed with no problems using html knitr. Have you already used this package (knitr) to perform other tasks? what package did you install? (I use install.packages("rmarkdown"))

Comment: Thanks Tal! That is very strange. I've used knitr before but I find this error to be very weird. Although I'm not sure if 'Rmarkdown' package is installed...

Comment: No problem Shivendra. Assuming all libraries are loaded, maybe it is just a small typo somewhere. Could try to help better if you post those few lines of code for inspection. Cheers.

Comment: I'll add some more details then.

Comment: So I am not sure I understand the code. Why are you using read.table to load a rds object and not readRds ? Also you are not assigning the object to anything.  
Can it be that your object exists in your global environment and thus the command works on your console but not in knitr? Do you mind trying the following 2 lines in knitr:  
    `wr <- read.table("repdata_data_StormData.csv", header = T, sep = ",", as.is = T, nrows = 100)`
`wr$PROPDMGEXP <- gsub('M', '0', wr$PROPDMGEXP)`  
Assuming the file _repdata_data_StormData.csv_ is in your current directory.

Comment: I used the read.table() because the file is originally in text format when unzipped. No issues over there as the table is fully functional and working in the environment. The code that I presented is just a snippet, not the real one as that is pretty long containing if,else loops. I did assign the object, as an example I showed replacing the 'K' with '1' in the PROPDMGEXP column. It works fine in the console but knitr throws off an error

Comment: Got it. So it seems the grouped data I was trying to form had some issues. I reloaded the storm.csv file and ran a gsub() function without any errors. The issue was definitely in one of the tables. Thanks for pointing out Tal!